# Why doesn't CUDA synchronization point prevent race condition?

Tags: c++, cuda, race-condition

We run the `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck <executable>` on our code.  We get the following memory hazard errors.

```
========= Race reported between Read access at 0x00004098 CUDA.cu:123:KernelFunction()
=========     and Write access at 0x00005058 in CUDA.cu:146:KernelFunction() [529996 hazards]
```

Here's the code.  It claims that line 123 `value = sharedMemory0[sharedMemoryIndex];` is in a race condition with line 146 `sharedMemory0[sharedIndex0] = sharedMemory1[sharedIndex1];`.  We have

```
// Synchronization Point 1 
__syncthreads(); 
__threadfence_block();
```

between the two lines. Shouldn't all the threads synchronize at that point and all the previous memory read/writes complete at that point?  All the threads and memory accesses should complete after the first j-loop before starting the second j-loop.  So in our minds Synchronization Point 1 should isolate the two j-loops and prevent a race condition, but the tool says that's not true.

Why is the tool reporting a race condition? Any insights as to what we could do to prevent it?

We've also seen references to a tool that might be able to report a trace of the execution to more easily see the race condition.  What tool and options can we use to get a trace to see more clearly why the race condition exists?

```
   for (i = 0; i < COUNT0; i++) {
       // Synchronization Point 0
       __syncthreads();
       __threadfence_block();
       for (j = 0; j < COUNT1; j++) {
          index = j*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
          if (index < THREAD_COUNT0) {
             for (k = 0; k < COUNT2; k++)
                sharedMemoryIndex = function0(index);
                value = sharedMemory0[sharedMemoryIndex];
             }
          }         
       }

       // Synchronization Point 1
       __syncthreads();
       __threadfence_block();
       for (j = 0; j < COUNT2; j++) {
          index = j*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
          if (index < THREAD_COUNT1) {
            sharedIndex0 = function1(index);
            sharedIndex1 = function2(index);
            sharedMemory0[sharedIndex0] = sharedMemory1[sharedIndex1];
          }
       }
    }
```

We've also run the Synccheck tool, `cuda-memcheck --tool synccheck <executable>` and it reported the following error on Synchronization Point 1.  There's probably a strong correlation between the two errors, but there isn't very much documentation in the cuda-memcheck guide about what synchronization of divergent code is, why it's bad, and how to fix it.

Any comments?

```
========= Barrier error detected. Encountered barrier with divergent threads in block
=========     at 0x00004ad8 in CUDA.cu:139:KernelFunction()
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (8,0,0)
```

Comment: Is every thread entering this for loop (first for i) ?  The message reads that some theads cannot reach line 139.

Comment: A snippet of code out of context is completely unhelpful for providing you with an answer. Please provide a complete kernel which someone else could compile and disassemble or analyse

Comment: Thanks @FlorentDUGUET.  Your suggestion helped clarify what a divergent thread means.

Comment: @talonmies  In an ideal world we'd be able to share the code with you.  Unfortunately we can't.  We actually spend a fair amount of time figuring out how to explain the problem in a simple way.  And we even spend a lot of time exploring the implications of comments and answers before we respond.  We understand that having the original source would be better, but that's the constraint we are faced with, and we try to be conscientious and thoughtful given that constraint.

Comment: @roger1994: Then you are in the wrong place. There is a reason this question has earned two downvotes and three close votes since you posted it. Your choice....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code gives the same results independently of the number of threads used to perform the calculations.  We ran the code with only a single thread and then ran the code with multiple threads.  By definition, it's not possible for a single threaded version to run into a race condition.  And yet, the single threaded version gave identical results to the multi-threaded version.  `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck` reports many, many race violations on the multi-threaded version.  If there were race violations actually occurring, the multi-threaded results would not match exactly the single threaded results.  Therefore, `cuda-memcheck` must be wrong and have bugs dealing with complex looping structures. `cuda-memcheck` was able to find race conditions in simple looping structures, just not in this complicated one.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough data to pinpoint your problem accurately. However, the last error message is very crucial:

```
Barrier error detected. Encountered barrier with divergent threads in block
```

Seems one of your threads in a block reaches some barrier while the other does not, because it is in a branch that is not taken. Note, that divergent branches occur not only in `if` conditions, but also in loops, if their looping condition is different between threads in a block.

When some threads miss a `__syncthreads()` because of it strange things may happen. In practice, it usually means that those threads stop at a *different* `__syncthreads()` and the system thinks everything is in sync when it is not. That can later lead to racing situations you describe.

So - find your divergent `__syncthreads()` -- that's most likely the cause of your problems. It could be that the problem is *before* the snippet you included.

Also:

- is `i` a local variable (not shared)?
- is `COUNT0` the same for all threads in a block?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful insights.  Yes, all of the for-loop indices are local variables, not shared.  Should they be shared?  And the loop conditions look like they are the same for all threads, but we are trying to understand this more clearly.

Comment: No, loop conditions *shouldn't* be shared. Doing so would create the problem you describe, so I wanted to make sure that case is covered.